# Retrieve database data with hover()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover, imagemap

I'm thinking of making an imagemap with hover, showing the total number of occurrence happened within the same loc_id.

### getOccCount.php

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT COUNT(occurrence_id) FROM major_occurrence GROUP BY location_id";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result    
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

The hover should change results whenever i mouseover to another location on imagemap since it's having different location id.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 950px;
        height: 1211px;
        background: url(images/Campus-Map.jpg);
        background-size: 950px 1211px;
        font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 8pt;
    }

    #map li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    #map li a {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        /*
       Specifying a background image
       (a 1px by 1px transparent gif)
       fixes a bug in older versions of
       IE that causeses the block to not
       render at its full dimensions.
    */
        background: url(blank.gif);
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
    }

    #map li a span {
        display: none;
    }

    #map li a:hover span {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 200px;
        left: 20px;
        top: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    #map a.rpc {
        top: 1060px;
        left: 585px;
        width: 78px;
        height: 65px;
    }
</style>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $('#map>span').hover(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'getOccCount.php',
                    data: "",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    method: GET,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var location_id = $(this).attr("location_id");
                        $.get("getOccCount.php", {location_id: location_id}, function (result) {
                            var result = data[0];
                            $('#map>span').html('Total Number of Occurrence: ' + result);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
<body>
    <html>
<ul id="map">
    <li><a class="rpc" href="doRPMap.php?locID=1"><span><b>RPC</b></span></a></li>
<ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

After making the necessary changes, it's still not working for me. Please give me some advise on this matter. Thanks.

Comment: Requesting server on each element hovering is a no go for sure...

Comment: Exactly, I would just have to move my mouse cursor over the element and out again and over again and … to flood your server with AJAX requests. If you can’t fetch the data up-front, then you should at least implement some form of caching, so that the next hover over the same element does not need to make a request again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful if you provided us with a bit more of your code, e.g. the html that actually draws the map (I only see one link, but nothing with id=map is actually printed on the webpage), and the javascript itself. But I'll try to answer your question anyways:

Since you're posting this with the `jquery` tag I'm assuming you have those libraries loaded. Basically, what you want to do is perform a $.get or $.post AJAX request when the hover() function is executed, and then do something with the result from that request.

First of all, you will have to provide the loc_id on every single 'map marker', to submit this to the page that will handle your request.
Here's an example, in which the image that you hover over has `class="image"` and a unique `loc_id="x"` attribute:

```
$('.image').mouseenter(function(){ 
    var loc_id = $(this).attr("loc_id");
    $.get("get_occurence_count.php", {loc_id: loc_id}, function(result) {
        //Handle result here.
    });
});
```

What this snippet does, is: it sends the `loc_id` from the `.image` that was hovered over to a PHP page called get_occurence_count.php. This PHP page will have to have a small script that opens a database connection, and gets the COUNT like you mentioned in your question, and then ECHO this number. This number that is echo'd on the PHP page will then be returned to the javascript as the variable `result`. Use this `result` in the section above where I stated "Handle result here".

For example: you can put the result in the hover div (or whatever you're using), by doing: $('.hover').html('The count for this location is: ' + result);

Hope this helps!

Edit: changed hover() to mouseenter() as per suggestion below. 
Edit2: added part on how to append results to the hover.

Comment: `this will call an ajax request on mouseenter/mouseleave (both events) each time. And these events can happen hundred times. This is answering question but this is a no go for sure`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I changed the code to use mouseenter only.

Comment: Ya, your edit is better but still... +1 because this is what is looking for OP

Comment: Then may i know how to echo out the results inside the hover?

Comment: I have added this to the answer above.

Comment: I've tried making changes to my existing codes, but it's seem not working. Can you please check on this? (Made changes to existing codes above)